# Python casting Tuple[int, int]

Tags: python, parsing, tuples

I have a string `"1,2"` that I am trying to parse into `(1, 2)` without simply splitting based on `,`. I was thinking intuitively something along the lines of:

```
from typing import Tuple
t = Tuple[int, int]("1,2")
```

This obviously doesn't work, but it seems logical to cast a specific tuple type (int, int) to a string for parsing. Thoughts?

Comment: In addition to the answer below I'll point out that python does not support "casting" in the sense you seem to mean it (i.e., a C lang cast). Yes, you can do things like `l = [1, 2]; t = tuple(l)` but that isn't "casting". You're calling a constructor that happens to know how to convert a list to a tuple.

Answer (score 2):

The `typing` module is for a completely different thing (type hinting). As far as I know, there's nothing built in to do this kind of thing. You need to manually parse or `eval` it.

Manually parsing is easy enough, simply split on `,` and convert each element to an `int`:

```
your_string = "1,2"
tuple(int(i) for i in your_string.split(","))
```

`eval`ing it allows for other data types to sneak in, but is more "automatic" (use `ast.literal_eval` for security reasons):

```
import ast

your_string = "1,2"
ast.literal_eval(your_string)
```

Comment: Yeah, I think splitting the string is the way to go. I was hoping I could cast somehow since it would be quite clean code.

Answer (score 0):

what Tomothy32 mentioned about manually parsing based on splitting by comma is correct.
You can also Use map for the above as below -

```
your_input = "1,2"
your_tuple = tuple(map(int, your_input.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple input like `"1,2"` splitting on `","` is the most straightforward solution.

If the input is more complex - perhaps it contains whitespace, or there are many possible separators - you could write a generator that yields the integers:

```
>>> data = '18 ,15 ,18,15x,19,14,20,12,13,17'
>>> def interator(data):
...     digits = []
...     for c in data:
...         if c.isdigit():
...             digits.append(c)
...         else:
...             if digits:
...                 yield int(''.join(digits))
...                 del digits[:]
...     if digits:
...         yield int(''.join(digits))
... 
>>> tuple(interator(data))
(18, 15, 18, 15, 19, 14, 20, 12, 13, 17)
```

As is often the case, there's an itertools one-liner that does the same thing:

```
>>> tuple(int(''.join(s)) for _, s in 
...       filter(lambda x: x[0], itertools.groupby(data, str.isdigit)))
(18, 15, 18, 15, 19, 14, 20, 12, 13, 17)
```

But a regex would be both concise *and* readable:

```
>>> tuple(int(x.group(0)) for x in re.finditer(r'\d+', data))
(18, 15, 18, 15, 19, 14, 20, 12, 13, 17)
```